Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 - how can I change the dark theme?
I like Ubuntu Studio (24.04.1) very much, but can't get on with the dark colors of the theme. I can hardly see anything!
I thought I had changed the theme to a light one, but some programs are still using a dark scheme.
For instance I installed FileZilla (dark!), and then gftp (also dark!).
There seem to be multiple different places to set themes, colors etc., it's all very confusing...  I have used Windows for years and, although I'm not a great fan of it, it is very simple to change the color scheme reliably across all applications.
What's going on? Is it because some applications run (or were written) under a different window manager?
It would be great if someone could give me details on how to reliably change the screen colors across the board. Surely it should be straightforward to do this?
Many thanks,
Peter

All applications run under the same window manager which is in your case kwin, the windowmanager for Plasma.
The plasma desktop is based on Qt, but the applications filezilla and gftp are based on GTK. filezilla uses GTK-3 and gftp uses GTK-2.
The theme you choose in the system setting applies to Qt-based applications, not to GTK-based applications. There is a special setting for GTK-based applications. Go to System Settings > Appearance > Application Style:

There click the button Configure Gnome/GTK Application Style... and choose your desired theme from the drop down menu:


That's great and has sorted it - many thanks!
